# Make correct URI for WP Game Library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to create a library with sounds in it, but I cant get the URIs to work, if I use a online uri like

```
new Uri("http://www.archive.org/download/BrahmsViolinConcerto-Heifetz/03Iii.AllegroGiocosoMaNonTroppoVivace.mp3")
```

it works fine, so the issue is linking correctly to my folders in my project

My in my WP Game Librarys folder I have \Sounds\letters and in that folder is a sound named a.wma

My Method for loading this is

```
public void PlayLetter(string letter)
    {
        try
        {
            Initialize();
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            var uri = new Uri(@"/Sounds/letters/" + letter + ".wma", UriKind.Relative);
            var song = Song.FromUri("sound", uri);
            MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And I of course give it string "a" as a parameter when it fails

I have also included the sound file in my project like

[image]

I just get a

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll

But its an uri problem I am certain as I tried a online URI that worked just fine

Also I am in doubt of 2 things, is MediaPlayer the right thing to use in a game? And can a library play sounds (Or even contain them)

Comment: the other difference is that your web version is an MP3.  not sure if that's the problem though...

Comment: Changing to a mp3 didnt help :)

Comment: What I can say for sure is that a library can play sounds and can contain them. Not sure about your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical thing in XNA would be to use a SoundEffectInstance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx

Unfortunately SoundEffectInstance only works with wav files. If you want to play back longer music files - you can use a MediaElement - but that allows for playback of a single compressed audio file at a time only. Another option might be to play compressed from the MediaLibrary using the MediaPlayer class. You could also save your own compressed audio file in the MediaLibrary to play it from there. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.songs.aspx